# How do I make this recursive function not give me the same lists but in different orders

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, recursion

I know this question is a bit confusing but you'll understand if you see the output, I'm really new to recursion so I'm still trying to get a grasp of the whole thing.

```
def coin_Exchange(n,m, flag = [0]):
    m = sorted(m)
    for current_number in m:
        if (current_number + (sum(flag))) == n:
            print(f"{flag + [current_number]} = {n}")
            return
        elif (current_number + (sum(flag))) > n:
            break
        else:
            temp_flag = flag + [current_number]
            coin_Exchange(n,m,temp_flag)

coin_Exchange(4,[1, 2])
```

So the intended out put should be :

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1] = 4
[0, 1, 1, 2] = 4
[0, 2, 2] = 4
```

But instead I get:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1] = 4
[0, 1, 1, 2] = 4
[0, 1, 2, 1] = 4
[0, 2, 1, 1] = 4
[0, 2, 2] = 4
```

I know why this happens, I just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the logic so as to proceed only forward:

```
def coin_Exchange(n,m, flag = [0]):
    m = sorted(m)
    for i, current_number in enumerate(m):
        if (current_number + (sum(flag))) == n:
            print(f"{flag + [current_number]} = {n}")
            return
        elif (current_number + (sum(flag))) > n:
            break
        else:
            temp_flag = flag + [current_number]
            coin_Exchange(n,m[i:-1],temp_flag)
```

At each iteration you reduce the available coins to coins that are of greater or equal value to the current one, thereby avoiding repeats.